# Line that follows a view?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create this `UIView` , that is connected with some line (`UIBezier`?), to a center point . Then when that view is moving with animation, where ever he moves , the line continuously keeps connecting it with the center , that means changing its length and angle seamlessly while stay between center and view.

So i know all kinds of manipulation with views, i know how to draw lines with `CAShapeLayer`  , and also `UIBezierpath` , but what is the most simple way , to connect this line to a centre  and forget about it? (= i can now play with that view and the line will follow )

Comment: Draw whatever you want on view's `layer`.

Comment: not sure i know what to take from it, can you go deep on that ?

Comment: Could you attach a picture with result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to put the view into a superview of custom view subclass and override `-drawRect:` of the superview.

Then it is easy to get the position of the subview, the center of the superview and to draw the line.